# Creating a template class member

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a class that will have a template class member. Allocator I will receive during the constructor call. This code throws an error:

```
error: data member ‘base’ cannot be a member template
   12 |   BaseExample<T, Allocator>* base;
```

The code:-

```cpp
#include <memory>

template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
struct BaseExample {
  // somethings
};

template <typename T>
class Example {
  // somethings
  template <typename Allocator>
  BaseExample<T, Allocator>* base;
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

I read similar questions, but everywhere they only talk about template functions.

Comment: You can't have a template as non-static data member. It is simply impossible. What do you intent to do with it? How do you want to use `base`? Why is `Allocator` not a template parameter of `Example`?

Comment: This is a tutorial, but as I understand it, the point is that we want to be able to change the Allocator when assigned.

Comment: It's impossible. The tutorial doesn't make sense if it asks you to do this. Or, maybe more likely, you misunderstood what it wants you to do.